# Why is the cursor selection to highlight text and perform copy/paste is not working on Chrome for my React app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI (V4). There is a Customized SnackBar component being used to display the messages from backed, like success and failure messages. But, I am unable to copy the message shown on the snackbar component. This issue is seen only on Chrome (the text selection is working fine on Safari browser). Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Icon } from '@material-ui/core';
import SmsFailedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SmsFailed';

const successIcon = () => (
  <Icon>
    <SmsFailedIcon />
  </Icon>
);

const failedIcon = () => (
  <Icon>
    <SmsFailedIcon />
  </Icon>
);
function Alert(props) {
  return (
    <MuiAlert
      elevation={6}
      variant="filled"
      {...props}
      iconMapping={{ success: successIcon, error: failedIcon }}
    />
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    '& > * + *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));

export default function CustomizedSnackbars() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open success snackbar
      </Button>
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
          This is a success message!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can anyone please advise ?

Comment: When I try to run your code in a codesandbox seems to work (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6q2p1b?file=/demo.js) are you using server side rendering (even if you use it should work)?

Comment: Hi @Akis, no we are not using server side rendering.